# Django Order_By Datetime

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a DateTime field, called Game.

When I called Game.objects.order_by('-date'), it mostly works. However, if two games have the same datetime, then they appear in reverse chronological order (in ascending pk order). IE, if you enter game1, then game2, game1 will appear as the most recent game. Is there any way to reverse this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the suborder to be reversed as well, you should state it explicitly:

```
Game.objects.order_by('-date', '-pk')
```